# Checking database acting as mirror

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my VB.NET app I'm doing some simple SELECTs against a SQL Server view. The view is on two linked server connections on our local SQL Server.

The two linked servers are changing from time to time its Master/Mirror behavior. So in my app I don't know which of the servers is actually the master.

At the moment I fire my query and catch the sqlexception which is something like: "the database is acting as mirror" if I get this exception I change the connection and do the query twice.

Is there a way to check the status of the server before firing queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your database is `Mirror` or `Principal` via using system table `sys.database_mirroring`

as next:-

```
DECLARE @MirroringRole int;
SET @MirroringRole = (SELECT mirroring_role
    FROM sys.database_mirroring
    WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = N'DB_X');   -- your database name here
IF @MirroringRole = 2 -- Mirror
    -- connect to other server, other database
ELSE IF @MirroringRole = 1 -- Principal
    -- connect to this server, this database >> DB_X
END IF
```

Hope it helps.